# Need for the definite article

Tags: definite-article

Should we add an article before "Supreme?"

> He is Supreme God .

> He is the Supreme God/Power

sounds better, but is it necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answer this with great hesitation, but I see that the question has received no other attention.

---

Take care not to say more than you mean or less than you mean.

If you are writing within a polytheistic belief system (e.g., Hinduism) then you can write about **the Supreme God**. Your point would be that ***this* god** is more powerful than **those *other* gods**.

If you are writing within a monotheistic belief system (e.g., Christianity, Islam) then you must not write about a **supreme god**, for doing so would suggest that **your god** is but one among many.

You might want **the Supreme Power.** This acknowledges that other **powers** exist, such as kings and governments, but that **your God** is more powerful than all of those.

**The supreme being** is also a common phrase—often in theological discussions

If you use the word **supreme**, you must use **the**, for **the supreme *anything*** is the ultimate in its class. There can be none better/higher/stronger etc. It is like saying **the best**.

Your choice of uppercase letters will indicate your own position on the being's supremacy. If you are a believer, you might choose uppercase. If you are a scholar or a journalist discussing the beliefs of others, you might prefer lowercase.